# sending http/2 POST request in Node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, http2, ksqldb, node-kafka-streams

How can send an http/2 post request in Node.js?
I want to send the following request.

```
curl --http2 "POST" "http://hostname:8088/query-stream" -d $'{"sql": "SELECT * FROM `USERPROFILE` EMIT CHANGES;", "properties": {"ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset": "earliest" } }'
```

Answer (score 0):

The package [fetch-h2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-h2) has http/2 support:

```
import { fetch } from 'fetch-h2'

const url = 'https://hostname:8088/query-stream'
const method = 'POST';
const json = {"sql": "SELECT * FROM `USERPROFILE` EMIT CHANGES;", "properties": {"ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset": "earliest" } };
 
const response = await fetch( url, { method, json } );
```

Note that by default fetch-h2 uses http/1.1 for http:// addresses.
Either change the URL or configure fetch-h2 to explicitly use http/2 even for http:// requests.

Comment: thanks for answering but I think fetch sending http/1.1  request. not support http/2 the response is this in that example 
{
  '@type': 'generic_error',
  error_code: 40004,
  message: 'This endpoint is only available when using HTTP2'
}
➜

Comment: You are correct.
I wasn't aware of that.
I changed my answer with a solution that should support http/2

Comment: Thank You.
I have used also fetch-h2 it also problematic for that request. 
for that request will open the connection and if any changes will send an event, like a socket.

response to that example is following` 
Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established